# Chosen Select Search via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to make `chosen select`'s search box work via ajax and fill dropdown with its result.

so far no success.

```
   $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ES1_ddlInstructor1_chosen input").change(function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
        FillList($(this).val(), "<%=Request.Url.AbsolutePath%>/FillList", "#<%=ddlInstructor1.ClientID%>");
    });

    function FillList(Search, url, Sub) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: "{ 'Search': '" + Search + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $(Sub).empty();

                if (data.d.length > 1)
                    $(Sub).html($('<option></option>').val("").html("Seçiniz.."))

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $(Sub).append($('<option></option>').val(data.d[i].UId).html(data.d[i].Text));
                }

                if (data.d.length == 1)
                    $(Sub).change();

                $(Sub).trigger("chosen:updated");

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: what is <option></option> you should using class or id

Comment: that filllist is working on somewhereelse, problem is actually reaching choosen selects inputs change.

Comment: Where is it going wrong? Is the ajax returning the correct result?

Comment: change is not firing

Comment: Change input selector to `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ES1_ddlInstructor1_chosen :input")`.